# wrapped text in ngx-datatable rows getting cut-off in print view

Tags: css, angular, ngx-datatable

I overwrote the css for ngx-datatable's `datatable-body-cell-label` class to allow the contents to wrap when printing. However, as an unwelcome side-effect, wrapped text is getting cut-off when the page breaks. [image] I attempted to remedy this by adding `page-break-inside: avoid;' to the css for both the`datatable-body-cell`and`datatable-body-cell-label` classes, but to no avail.

ngx-datatable in template:

```
    <ngx-datatable class="material results-grid engagement-specifics" [rows]="engagementSpecifics"
                   [columns]="engagementSpecificsGridColumns"
                   [headerHeight]="30" [footerHeight]="0" [rowHeight]="70"
                   [rowClass]="getEngagementSpecificsRowClass"
                   *ngIf="showReport(['engagementSpecifics'])">
    </ngx-datatable>
```

relevant css:

```
.datatable-body-cell {
    @media print {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
  }

  .datatable-body-cell-label {
    @media print {
      // allow text wrapping
      white-space: normal !important;
      page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @soccer7 a minimal reproducible on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8n66zopr9l?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) will be useful to understand the issue.

Comment: Your URL errors out in browser section `ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: '../@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css' relative to '/package.json'`

Comment: @soccer7 I gave up on ngx-datatable for this use case and used `mat-table` instead.

Answer (score 0):

We need block-level elements to avoid rows cropping:

```
@media print {
    ::ng-deep .datatable-scroll {
        display: block !important;
    }

    ::ng-deep .datatable-row-wrapper {
        display: block !important;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

Note: `page-break-inside` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside), please use `break-inside` instead.